# Can you refer to "THIS" as "IT"? For example: Is THIS the library? a) Yes, IT is. b) Yes, THIS is

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, idiomatic-language, pronouns, dummy-pronouns

This is from the British council's speaking content. *A student is looking for the library and comes to the place, but he is not sure if he came to the right place. So he asks:*

**Student: Is this the library?**

**Librarian: Yes, it is. Quiet, please.**

I found the answer interesting in that the question starts with **"IS THIS ....."** but the librarian answers using **"yes, IT IS."**

Why did the librarian answer **"IT is....",** wherease the student asked the question using **"Is THIS ......?** What would happen if the librarian said **"Yes, THIS is the library"?** Would it be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

We use *this* (the place where we are, or a thing near the speaker) or *that* (a thing further away) to identify what we are talking about. Once it's been established what we are talking about, the place or thing can be referred to as *it.*